# ImagePicker IOS errors i don't understand and don't know how to fix

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

i want the user to select an image out of the iphone when they press on a button (via action: buttonClicked), and i want that image to view on the imageview i have (imageAddPicture is the name of the image view)

I found a lot of information but when i use this code i get following errors:

self, release, picker.sourceType = (sender == buttonClicked),...

can someone help me please? (i'm new to stackoverflow.com but i really need the help, i'll try to help other people to)
This is the code i used:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = (sender == buttonClicked) ?    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    imageAddPicture.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Could you write the full error into your question?

Comment: I found out what was wrong with 2 errors i only have this error left:
at the word "release" it gives this 2 errors:
-ARC forbids expllicit message send of 'release'
-'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: Can you edit your question and write that into it in that case?

Comment: also there is an other error here\

Comment: picker.sourceType = (sender == buttonClicked) ?    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

buttonClicked should be buttonClicked:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working your project in Automatic Reference counting. So you don't need to release objects. Simply remove this line. Chil :)

```
picker.sourceType = (sender == buttonClicked) ?    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```

this line should be

```
picker.sourceType = (sender == buttonClicked:) ?    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I don't get error messages but when I click the button i go to this error in my xcode screen:
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  (error:SIGABRT)

Comment: there is a log below. copy the complete error from there and post it here

Comment: [buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a5460
2012-10-24 11:18:39.896 Mundo Grafia[5693:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a5460'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c98012 0x10d5e7e 0x1d234bd 0x1c87bbc 0x1c8794e 0x10e9705 0x20920 0x208b8 0xe1671 0xe1bcf 0xe0872 0x5016d 0x50552 0x2e3aa 0x1fcf8 0x1bf3df9 0x1bf3ad0 0x1c0dbf5 0x1c0d962 0x1c3ebb6 0x1c3df44 0x1c3de1b 0x1bf27e3 0x1bf2668 0x1d65c 0x22fd 0x2225)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: you'r not assigning method to button properly. did you attached it through interface or through programming

Comment: if through interface then remove it and attach it again

Comment: Yes, it's correct but i couldn't put the full error in this box because of max characters

Comment: I see that the only difference is the ":" when i add it i get this error: expected: ')'

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanding, srry. I edited the code to get it to work and its sender == clickSelectPicture
(its the name of the button so that's correct)

Comment: But how do i get rid of the SIGABRT error. I've had it more times and still don't understand it. Also is it maybe a problem that my iphone simulator doesn't have pictures in it?

Comment: put your error here now again. remove it from last if charecters are too large

Comment: part1:

2012-10-24 11:40:21.279 Mundo Grafia[5807:c07] -[ViewControllerAddPicture buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759c880
2012-10-24 11:40:21.282 Mundo Grafia[5807:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewControllerAddPicture buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759c880'

Comment: part2: *** First throw call stack:
(0x1c98012 0x10d5e7e 0x1d234bd 0x1c87bbc 0x1c8794e 0x10e9705 0x20920 0x208b8 0xe1671 0xe1bcf 0xe0872 0x5016d 0x50552 0x2e3aa 0x1fcf8 0x1bf3df9 0x1bf3ad0 0x1c0dbf5 0x1c0d962 0x1c3ebb6 0x1c3df44 0x1c3de1b 0x1bf27e3 0x1bf2668 0x1d65c 0x22fd 0x2225)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: and this on top of it all:
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 5807.

Comment: so this is that you have not attached proper method with button. review it